# Option clash for [framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} & [draft]{graphicx} | same clash for [demo]{graphicx}

Tags: graphics, mdframed, option-clash

The following combination of options and packages gives an `Option clash`, and thus prohibits anybody from compiling the code:

- `\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}`
- `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` (or `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`)

Who knows how to ommit the `Option clash`, but still keep using both lines of code in the same document?

### MnotWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % only 1 of them can be loaded
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % only 1 of them can be loaded (regardless of whether you use the "demo" or "draft" optional argument)

\begin{document}

If you try to include both of the lines (the ones commented above), the error is: \textbf{LaTeX Error Option clash for package graphicx.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've removed the `tikz-pgf` tag, since this is not related to the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the call to graphicx before mdframed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % 


\begin{document}

\includegraphics{blub}

\end{document}
```

Or pass the option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % 

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{blub}

\end{document}
```

Or use the documentclass option:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % 


\begin{document}

\includegraphics{blub}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `demo` as an option to `article` class. Since `mdframed` loads `graphicx` you don't need to load `graphicx` (and that's the cause of the clash initially)

In any case, the `demo` option must be known to `mdframed` before it loads `graphicx` with other (conflicting) options.

This is a general rule, not restricted to `graphicx` etc.

Another example could be the options of `xcolor`, also causing trouble sometimes!

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % only 1 of them can be loaded
%\usepackage{graphicx} % only 1 of them can be loaded (regardless of whether you use the "demo" or "draft" optional argument)


\begin{document}

If you try to include both of the lines (the ones commented above), the error is: \textbf{LaTeX Error Option clash for package graphicx.}

\includegraphics{ente}

\end{document}
```